# How to split validation from input into two separate methods?

Tags: c#

I have the following method and I want to separate the input part from the validation part, i.e. I want to read the input in one method (`ReadInput`) and to assert that the input value is of type `double` in another method (`AssertIsDouble`). How can I do that?

```
public static double ReadInput()
{
    double number = 0;

    while (true)
    {

        if (Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number) && number > 0)
        {
            return number;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please, input a number greater than zero (0).");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
public static double ReadInput()
{
    double number = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        AssertIsDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}

private static double AssertIsDouble(string input)
{
    double number = 0.0;

    if (Double.TryParse(input, out number) && number > 0)
    {
        return number;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please, input a number greater than zero (0).");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Valentin No you don't want to use exceptions to control program flow.

Comment: Where are you returning the number too?

Comment: you've got an infinite loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use an `out` parameter along with returning a `bool` from the `Assert` method.

<sup>Disclaimer: The code is untested but should work.</sup>

```
public static double ReadInput()
{
    double number;

    while (!AssertIsDouble(Console.ReadLine(), out number))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please, input a number greater than zero (0).");
    }

    return number;
}

public bool AssertIsDouble(string input, out double number)
{
    return (Double.TryParse(input, out number) && number > 0);
}
```

Note that if I was you I'd also rename the methods as they are a bit unclear at the moment:

- `ReadInput`: Read what input, as what?
- `AssertIsDouble`: Not a bad name but it also does additional checks.

Also note the problem with your original code is this loop:

```
while (true)
{
    AssertIsDouble(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

You never check/assign the return value from the method call and never set a condition to break out of the loop, thus you have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

What I commonly do to get strongly typed (non-string) input from the user is to have a separate method that takes in a prompt to display to the user, an error prompt to display if they enter an incorrect value, and the min/max values allowed for the input. This greatly simplifies the main code body:

```
private static double GetDoubleFromUser(
    string prompt = "Please enter a number: ",
    string errorPrompt = " - Error: input must be a number between {0} and {1}: ",
    double minValue = double.MinValue, double maxValue = double.MaxValue)
{
    double value;

    // Write the prompt text and get input from user
    if (prompt != null) Console.Write(prompt, minValue, maxValue);

    while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value)
            || value < minValue || value > maxValue)
    {
        // If input can't be converted to a double or is out of range, keep trying
        if (errorPrompt != null) Console.Write(errorPrompt, minValue, maxValue);
    }

    // Return converted input value
    return value;
}
```

Now, in your main body of code, you would just do something like:

```
double input = GetDoubleFromUser("Please input the amount: ", 
    "- input must be a number greater than zero: ", 0);

Console.WriteLine($"You entered: {input}");
```

And the method handles the rest:

[image]

Comment: I do like the method, but I'd have a default `prompt` and `errorPrompt` at the moment if they aren't entered the user has to guess why the program is paused. Better yet make them be required parameters. Also probably best to do some error checking on them i.e. not `null`, not all whitespace etc.

Comment: Also you could make it a generic method, although that would mean you can't default the min and max values. Whether that is bad for you depends on your situation.

Comment: I prefer to leave that type of checking to the user of the method. I have some code that uses whitespace for indenting, and the prompt has already been displayed, so it calls this method with no prompt and a whitespace error message.

Comment: That just seems like odd design, why display a prompt before calling a method designed to display the prompt for you? But I agree with the indenting as long as it is obvious to the user what they need to do again.

Comment: The prompt was part of the rules being displayed in a game. But I agree, having some overloads with default values would be a good idea. I updated the answer with some more sensible defaults.